# Group array by date and set value as keys

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, grouping

I have an array like this

```
 0 => 
array (size=3)
  'datetime_read' => '2017-07-16 20:45:08'
  'parameter_name' =>  'Rainfall Amount'
  'reading' => '0.00'

 1 => 
array (size=3)
  'datetime_read' =>  '2017-07-16 20:45:08'
  'parameter_name' =>  'Rainfall Intensity'
  'reading' =>  '0.0'

2 => 
array (size=3)
  'datetime_read' => '2017-07-16 20:45:08' 
  'parameter_name' => 'Air Pressure' 
  'reading' =>  '77.45'
```

and I need to group the data per date and get the values of parameter names and reading

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            'datetime_read' => '2017-07-16 20:45:08'
            'Rainfall Amount' => '0.00'
            'Rainfall Intensity' => '0.0'
            'Air Pressure' => '77.45'
        )
```

Comment: Did you try a loop or what did you try?

Comment: How are you getting the values for the array?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes i tried a loop but my solution makes a multi dimensional array.

Comment: @Vagabond from an sql query

Comment: [Pivot an array with a body-less foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71807961/2943403) then call `sort()` because the first element is what you are sorting on anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming `$input` is your input):

```
$combined = array_reduce(
    $input,
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        $datetimeRead = $item['datetime_read'];
        $parameterName = $item['parameter_name'];
        $reading = $item['reading'];

        $carry[$datetimeRead['datetime_read'] = $datetimeRead;
        $carry[$datetimeRead][$parameterName] = $reading;

        return $carry;
    },
    []
);

ksort($combined);

$data = array_values($combined);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the answer! I encounter an error just a missing ")" in the function clause.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. This is how I would solve it:

1. Look for the array with the max size and write a loop that goes till that max value
2. Initialize a new array outside the loop. This is going to be the final array
3. Each time you traverse the loop, check the dates of all these arrays. If the date already exists in the new array, then simply add these parameters. Otherwise, you'll have to add the date too in the array.